# About arrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have in my app a `ListView` with  `adapter`, I use this to show a list with a `chechbox` and a `textView`

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int position;

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public MyListAdapter (Context context, List<Model> listMeasurement){
        super(context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.empty, listMeasurement);
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        Model model= (Model)this.getItem(position);
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

My question is:

I want to show another `list` in another `activity`, this will have an `image`, two `textViews` and a `button`. The image depends on the value of the `textView`.

The best way to do this is do other `ArrayAdapter`? or use other things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry SBerg413, I don´t understand.

Comment: You've asked 10 questions but you have accepted none of the answers. Go through your previously asked questions and accept answers (click the checkmark).

Comment: When you like an answer, you need to "accept" and / or "upvote" it to mark it as the best or most useful one. Of your previous questions, you have not marked any as "accepted" and you have not upvoted any answers. This is why people don't answer your questions.

Comment: oh ok thanks, I am new in this page... I don´t know how used well. Sorry

Comment: It would be useful to quote the whole of your existing getView implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the `BaseAdapter` and override the `getView()` method. Here is a sample.

```
    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<Model> list;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> list) {
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                    return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
           return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            // If the view is null inflate it from xml
            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            // Bind xml to java
           ImageView icon = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
           TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
                       text.setText(list.get(position).getText());
                       icon.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).getDrawable());

           return view;
       }

   }
```

Comment: hello Sbossb thanks, but i don´t understand very well how this fix it my problem!!!. I have two view very different, I don't understand how i will to use the same adapter for show different thinks. thanks

Comment: you can't use the same adapter. you need to write a different adapter for each different list view row layout. What is confusing you about my answer?

Comment: No, now is ok, i think that I could  use the same adapter to different view. Thanks a lot.